# how to script for sharepoint app using jmeter for performance testing

Tags: sharepoint, jmeter, performance-testing, sharepoint-online

I am having a SharePoint-based application, using which I need to perform load testing.
But When I m recording the script, the response is not as same as the browser, and thus unable to get what needs to be done
And in first 2 requests:
get page
post login
in these, there is no dynamic value, so I am not able to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan
2. Second check all fields of the request from the browser (i.e. using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)) and JMeter and pay attention to [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
3. And last but not the least very often Sharepoint installations are protected using [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) or [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)), if this is the case you will need to add properly configured [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager), see [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more details.